# How to set font path in FPDF

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error:

```
include(/gravity/school/pdf/font/helveticab.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xamp\htdocs\gravity\school\pdf\fpdf.php on line 1144
```

Can anyone tell me how to set the fontpath?

Comment: I have added some markup and tried to improve the general question.

Comment: You can also set it like this `$pdf->fontpath = '/path/to/your/fonts'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place font file anywhere in your project folder, the best way to place font file is `fpdf/fonts`, Where `fpdf` is your library folder which you are using to generate PDFs. Then after set the fonts as below:

```
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','/Path/to/font');
require('fpdf.php');

// Arial bold 14
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
```

You can refer official doc for more information: [SetFont FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setfont.htm)

Comment: i am using first time fpdf so place the file in my project folder is that correct or i have to place fpdf file to other location.

Comment: define('FPDF_FONTPATH','/school/pdf/font'); i set this path but still getting error

Comment: Does your file has read permission? and font file should have .ttf format, I believe